# WebRTC PeerConnection crashes on setLocalDescription()

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc

I am trying to start a "call" using PeerConnection. I start by creating an the offer and pass in a callback which calls `setLocalDescription()` on the `PeerConnection`. However, this crashes the application with a null exception. Here is the stacktrace

```
2019-05-23 00:10:23.583 13684-14658/me.amryousef.homedoor A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6c in tid 14658 (worker_thread -)
2019-05-23 00:10:23.628 538-4027/? E/QCamera: <HAL><ERROR> processCaptureRequest: 4865: Did not find matching stream to update index
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3:8.0.0/OPR1.170623.032/47:user/release-keys'
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13684, tid: 14658, name: worker_thread -  >>> me.amryousef.homedoor <<<
2019-05-23 00:10:23.649 14736-14736/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6c
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6c
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x0   000000749d387ff0  x1   000000749d388008  x2   000000749a400000  x3   0000000000000003
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000141  x5   8000000000000000  x6   ff63646a6e756471  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   91cee4b1723ef4f4  x10  0000000000000000  x11  000000749d388008
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x12  00000000ffffffff  x13  00000000ffffff80  x14  000000000000000d  x15  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x16  00000074bcf32cb0  x17  00000074bced0f2c  x18  000000749d3861ec  x19  000000749cc54000
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000000  x21  000000749b816998  x22  000000749cc54200  x23  0000000000000000
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000000  x25  000000749b816454  x26  000000749cc540f0  x27  000000749d593dd1
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000000022308b  x29  000000749d388060  x30  000000749da066e4
2019-05-22 23:46:39.120 13650-13650/? A/DEBUG:     sp   000000749d387ff0  pc   000000749da066e8  pstate 0000000060000000
```

The full implementation of the `PeerConnection` handling can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/amrfarid140/7ad77b50af7c5b120b819a17bc0deaff)

What would be the cause of this `null pointer dereference`? What's missing in the process of creating the `offer`?

---

Here's how I built the PeerConnection

```
peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory
            .builder()
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()
```

and I am using the following version

`"org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.27771"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was not setting any video codecs (encode/decoder) factories. This became a requirement at some point according to the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/SKSkOUHXB2A/hx7AS4FkCgAJ).

The fix was to build the `PeerConnection` like this:

```
peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory
            .builder()
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext))
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, true, true))
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the google-webrtc version problem. but i don't know why. you should not use the 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'. you can try a proper version, like 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24277'

'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+' use the version 1.0.28032-0，and will fail to setLocalDescription( the sdp has no VP8 info)

Comment: i think sdp is based on devices, not by webrtc version